# Spring batch: NotSerializableException

Tags: java, spring

I have pojo class that is used by Spring batch job.

```
public class DataItem{
    String key;
    CellType type; //Enum
    String name;

    private XSSFCell cell; //org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell


   //getters setters omitted
}
```

When I try to run the batch job I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to serialize object of type: class org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution
    at org.springframework.util.SerializationUtils.serialize(SerializationUtils.java:49)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobExecutionDao.copy(MapJobExecutionDao.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobExecutionDao.updateJobExecution(MapJobExecutionDao.java:104)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.update(SimpleJobRepository.java:162)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:351)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
    at  com.excelreader.AppMain.run(AppMain.java:35)
    at  com.excelreader.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:16)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.excelreader.pojo.DataItem
```

Comment: Try to add `implements Serializable` to this class.

Comment: Why do I need explicitly indicate that?

Comment: it fails now on: Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell

Comment: Looks like `org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell` is not serializable. That is the main problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`DataItem` and everything inside it must implement `Serializable` interface. That's why you're getting this exception.